# nginx redirecting all traffic, not just server_name

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for several node servers. I recently added SSL to one of the projects.

My config looks a little like this:

```
# domain1
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.domain1.com
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://123.456.789.012:3001;
        # ... other proxy stuff
    }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.domain1.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This works perfectly for domain1. HTTPS works, and HTTP redirects to HTTPS.

*However*, this has somehow affected *another* domain on the same server. Here's its config:

```
# domain2
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.domain2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://123.456.789.012:3002;
        # ... all the other proxy stuff
    }
}
```

What's happening is, when I go to http://domain2.com, I get redirected to https://domain2.com, which complains because I don't have an SSL certificate for that domain.

When I remove the second server block from domain1, the one that forwards traffic on 80 to https, domain2 works again.

It seems to me that nginx is ignoring the `server_name` property, and forwarding all traffic to HTTPS. I've tried using hard URLs as well:

```
server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com
```

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, so there must be some obvious problem, but I can't see it!

Comment: First, do you have a `default_server` (as in `listen 80 default_server`)? Second, are you sure you destroyed your browser cache?  `301`s are cached by the browser, you should use `302`s while testing configuration.  Third, `*.domain2.com` will not catch `domain2.com`, you should be using `.domain2.com` (without the asterisk).

Comment: Thanks @grochmal! I removed the asterisks and switched to `302` redirects, and everything works! Must've been a caching issue.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @grochmal, I believe this was a simple caching issue. By switching to 302 Found redirects instead of 301s, and using a new browser, I was able to get the correct results.

I also corrected the wildcards, which may have been the original problem.